# How to change "key" and "value" keys of to_entries to "ParameterKey" and "ParameterValue" in jq?

Tags: jq

I have 3 json files that when merged using `*` produces the following result:

```
$ jq -s '.[0] * .[1] * .[2] | to_entries' a.json b.json c.json
[
  {
    "key" : "...",
    "value" : "..."
  },
  {
    "key" : "...",
    "value" : "..."
  },
  {
    "key" : "...",
    "value" : "..."
  }
]
```

How can I use different names for "key" and "value", e.g.:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey" : "...",
    "ParameterValue" : "..."
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey" : "...",
    "ParameterValue" : "..."
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey" : "...",
    "ParameterValue" : "..."
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new object and assign the fields correspondigly

```
… | .[] |= {ParameterKey: .key, ParameterValue: .value}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WipBR4iJ5-)

Instead of the update operator `|=` you could also use `map`

```
… | map({ParameterKey: .key, ParameterValue: .value})
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/N1rViircGt)

Depending on the actual structure of your three input files, this can probably be simplified using `reduce` instead.

Also, if you want to import the actual replacement names from outside jq (as their sample names suggest), use the `--arg` parameter to create an externally initialized variable and use it when creating the objects

```
jq -s --arg key "ParameterKey" --arg value "ParameterValue" '
  … {($key):.key, ($value):.value} …
'
```